# Как исправить регистрацию метода OnMouseDrag в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня есть метод OnMouseDrag. Проблема в том, что я использую его на телефоне и если нажать несколькими пальцами по экрану, образуются баги. Мне нужно чтобы метод регистрировал только первый клик, это можно как то сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете старую систему ввода (input system), то вы можете отследить нажатия пальцев через индекс метода Input.GetTouch(0). Создайте дополнительное условие в вашем методе OnMouseDrag, тогда вы сможете использовать логику и данные только первого прикоснувшегося пальца при перетаскивании)